# Whats the easiest way to create an Admin Panel for dynamic websites?

Tags: database, web-frameworks, administration

I've heard about web frameworks like [Rails](http://rubyonrails.org/), [Django](http://www.djangoproject.com/), [CakePHP](http://cakephp.org/) and others, that help programmers to quickly create dynamic websites which are basically a web GUI to interact with a database.

I was wondering if there are ways to "generate" these Admin Panel GUIs pretty much automatically, something like a Microsoft Access for the web? Where the "database" can be designed by non-programmers, and the resulting web app to work with that data be generated automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to go for RubyOnRails, it's just perfect for this purpose.

You just have to spend your time learning ruby and rails (in stackoverflow you can find a lot of suggestion about "how to start")

After that these are the key elements you need:

ActiveResource - is a library that allow you creates a persistable domain model from business objects and database tables, where logic and data are presented as a unified package. Zero configuration...

Scaffold or NiftyScaffold - A Rails Scaffold is an autogenerated framework for manipulating a model.

If u need a better interface have a look at the [web-app-theme generator](http://gravityblast.com/2009/07/30/2-minutes-admin-layout-with-rails-and-the-web-app-theme-generator/)

I don't add others word, check this framework and have a look at some [RailsCasts](http://railscasts.com/) in order to understand the power of ROR.

Comment: +1 Helpful but unrelated. I was talking about non-programmer solutions.

Comment: Not all web hotels lets you use "non-standard" languages either. Ofcourse, you can always switch to someone who does.